# Try/Except block declaring multiple values

Tags: python

I am trying to write a try/except block that declares two variables that retrieve their values via `ConfigParser`. The issue I am running into is that it is possible that one or both the values being declared may not be present under a particular section and should be set to `None` in such a case.  I am aware that I can simply add the values under to every config file, however, not all of the configs are consistent in section names which turns into a very tedious task.

Is there a better way to achieve the following try/except block without breaking them up into two separate ones?

```
try:
    ports = getCfgStr(sectName, 'ports')
    terminal = getCfgStr(sectName, 'terminals')
except KeyError:
    # Need to set ports or terminal to None depending on which raised the KeyError
```

My workaround solution:

```
try:
    ports = getCfgStr(sectName, 'ports')
except KeyError:
    ports = None

try:
    terminals = getCfgStr(sectName, 'terminals')
except KeyError:
    terminals = None
```

Comment: For those who are interested, [PEP-463](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0463/) addresses this issue.

Comment: Why a single try/except block is wrong: if `ports` is the one that generates the `KeyError`, you'll never even try to get the value for `terminals`. When writing a `try` block, each line of code should only be necessary if the lines before it don't raise an exception.

Comment: what is `getCfgStr`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question!

How about this:

```
def lookup(param):
    try:
        return getCfgStr(sectName, param)
    except KeyError:
        return None

ports = lookup('ports')
terminal = lookup('terminals')
```

Comment: Good point! The function can be even better with default value passed as not required argument: ```def lookup(sectName, param, default=None):...```

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to make your `getCfgStr` function able to accept default values, which it will return if there is no such option in section. So your code will be like this:

```
ports = getCfgStr(sectName, 'ports', None)
terminal = getCfgStr(sectName, 'terminals', None)
```

If you *have to* use exceptions, your solution is OK.

Comment: My `getCfgStr` function is the one that raises the `KeyError` exception.  I actually incorporate a global default config file that contains the defaults of all sections and items that are consistent among all the other configs, however, as I mentioned in my question, this is an odd case scenario where the sections and items may vary, and as such, are not added to the global default config.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just make a function:

```
def get_or_default(name, default):
    try:
        result = getCfgStr(sectName, name)
        return result
    except KeyError:
        return default
```

Call like this:

```
 ports = get_or_default('ports', None)
```

However a better approach if you are using `ConfigParser` would be to alter the `getCfgStr` function to use the libraries way of doing this: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/configparser.html#fallback-values

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the anti-pattern of [coding by exception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_by_exception), you could explicitly check if the option is present:

```
RawConfigParser.has_option(section, option)
```

> If the given section exists, and contains the given option, return True; otherwise return False.